# Generic HTTP Handler in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I want to write a custom HTTP Handler in ASP.Net (I'm using C# currently) that filters all requests to, say, .aspx files, and then, depending on the page name that comes with the requests, I redirect the user to a page.

So far, I've written a handler that filter "*", that is, everything. Let's say I receive a request for "Page.aspx", and want to send the user to "AnotherPage.aspx". So I call Redirect on that response and pass "AnotherPage.aspx" as the new page. The problem is that this will once more trigger my handler, which will do nothing. This will leave the user without any response.

So, is there a way to send the request to the other handlers (cascade the message) once I've dealt with it?

Thanks,
Bruno

Comment: Being pragmatic - could you not just use ASP.NET MVC or the routing framework now available in ASP.NET?

Comment: @Marc: Could you please provide some links to tutorials that would show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since Mark hasn't provided a full anwer containing the advice on MVC, here it goes what I learned:*

ASP.Net MVC can do that. In fact, ASP.Net MVC was designed for that purpose: with MVC you can map different *sub-links* in your website to the same Controller, which will then process the request and send a view (page) back to the user. This technique is called Url Routing and is explained in [ScottGu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) quite well.

Scott's also have other articles describing MVC, which are worth [checking out](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/02/12/asp-net-mvc-framework-road-map-update.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Page.PreviousPage or Page.IsCrossPagePostBack should let you know.

Comment: Ok, but once I know that the event come from my own handler, how do I pass it to the default ASP handlers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing in your implementation of it. I can't offer detailed advice. :(